# How To Render React Component When Using array.splice()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a button in my component that will execute DeleteNote property which i want to remove an array element on onClick event.

```
DeleteNote = (id) =>
{
    const allNotes = [...this.state.notes];
    const selectedNoteIndex = allNotes.findIndex(e => e.id == id)

    allNotes.splice(selectedNoteIndex, 1)
    this.setState({ notes: allNotes })
}
```

But this method seems to not re-render the component.

Anyway when i try with this method, it re-render perfectly.

```
MoveToArchive = (id) =>
{
    const allNotes = [...this.state.notes];
    const selectedNoteIndex = allNotes.findIndex(e => e.id == id)

    allNotes[selectedNoteIndex].archived = true;
    this.setState({ notes: allNotes })
}
```

What is lacking in my DeleteNote property in order to delete an element?
Been reading all resources but nothing seems to work.

Render :

```
Display = () =>
{
    return (
        <>
            <HeaderContainer notesData={this.state.notes} searchMethod={this.SearchNotes} />
            <MainContainer notesData={this.state.notes} deleteMethod={this.DeleteNote} archiveMethod={this.MoveToArchive} activeMethod={this.MoveToActive} />
            <NewModal />
            <DeleteModal deleteAllMethod={this.DeleteAllNotes} />
        </>
    )
}

render()
{
    return (this.Display())
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that renders `allNotes`?

Comment: Sure, is it the correct way of drilling props?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use `array.splice`? `array.filter` is simpler and usually used in these cases. It also doesn't alter the value of the original array so no need to copy `state.notes`. Not to mention that it would turn `DeleteNote` into just 1-2 lines of code.

Comment: @tomleb your approach of using `array.filter` is work, but i'm wondering is it going to work when i implementing search functionality that filters this.state.notes?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't. Note that in `DeleteNote` you are setting the `state` with the new array. The search functionality should work differently and not alter the notes in the state. It can work with either a seperate state piece for "filtered notes" or maybe even without a state, just a function that returns the filtered results based on the user search.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DeleteNote = (id) =>
{
    const allNotes = [...this.state.notes];
    const selectedNoteIndex = allNotes.findIndex(e => e.id == id)

    allNotes.splice(selectedNoteIndex, 1)
    this.setState({ notes: [...allNotes] })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code for deleting

```
DeleteNote = (id) => {
    const newNotes = this.state.notes.filter(e => e.id !== id)
    this.setState({ notes: newNotes })
}
```